# User Authentication in CakePhp 2.0 with Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, cakephp, oracle10g, pdo, cakephp-2.0

Fatal error: Call to a member function quote() on a non-object in C:..\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php on line 329

Can anybody help me for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain the Oracle DBO is ready yet. Currently I believe it only supports MySQL, Postgres, SqlLite, and SQLServer. Here is something that was posted on October. I'm not sure about the progress though.

http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/any_news_about_oracle_datasource_with_cakephp_2_0